# What's the next step for this Kakuro puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

What's the next step for the below Kakuro puzzle?

[image: Kakuro puzzle]

Source: Puzzle Page app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the row where you need to make 41 from 8 numbers:

> Since all 9 possible numbers together add up to 45, there can be no '4' in this row. Remove both pencilled-in 4's from consideration and remove the other pencil-mark numbers that depended on them to get a more accurate set of possibilities:
>
>  [image: Step 1]
>
>  Now there is only one place in that row to place the '6', then the '7', then the '8':
>
>  [image: Step 2]

That's the breakthrough you need. Now just follow the deductions like normal and you will eventually end up with the following final solved grid (SPOILER WARNING! Only reveal if you really want to see it!):

> [image: Full solution]

Comment: Thanks again! The first sentence of your first spoiler is key, and I'll try to remember that whenever I see 36-44 in 8

Comment: @Kidburla If you see anything *other* than 36-44 in 8, something is very wrong with the puzzle :) Similar "which *two* digits are missing" logic can also apply to 7 cell boxes, when you already know some of the digits (or if the missing digits can only be 1 2 or 8 9, etc).

Comment: @alephzero great point! I will definitely keep that in mind whenever I see 7 or 8 boxes in a row